# What is the best way to rotate cube in Opengl

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, rotation, rubiks-cube

I have a Rubik's cube displayed using OpenGl in a Java Eclipse application and I want to "rotate" this cube in response to mouse events.

I started with a "naive" (isn't it ?) solution as described here: [OpenGL - moving camera with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426415/opengl-moving-camera-with-mouse). With such solution in addition to the problem described (my problem is maybe the same ???) when I rotate 90 degrees according X-Axis to get 'upside front' i am not to rotate anymore according initial Y-Axis to get the new front on the right. Because of the first 90 degrees rotaion I will have now to rotate according to Z to get expected behavior.

May be using gluLookAt utility method is easiest than using modeling transformation in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would [arcball](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=48) make you happy ? (it should)

(I don't usually link to NeHe, but this one is independent from openGL)